# Cannot get any rate's value

Tags: json, reactjs, api, load

I am trying to load the data from exchangeratesapi but some how I cannot load the exchangerates's data!!

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({loading: true})
        fetch("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data)
                this.setState({
                    loading: false,
                    currency: data,
            })
            })
    }
```

```
  render() {
        var text = this.state.loading ? "loading..." : this.state.currency.BGN
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{this.state.currency.RON}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

I have try on of the dumbest way to load the data.

```
omponentDidMount() {
        this.setState({loading: true})
        fetch("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data)
                this.setState({
                    loading: false,
                    currency: data,
                    bulgaria:data.rates.BGN,
      })
            })
    }
```

And inside of `render`

```
var text = this.state.loading ? "loading..." : this.state.currency.bulgaria
```

But I believe there got a to be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the property directly from `currency` however, it exists in `rates`.

This is incorrect:

```
{this.state.currency.RON}
```

It should be:

```
{this.state.currency.rates.RON}
```

Similarly, the variable text you created is not used anywhere. IMHO it should be like this:

```
    render() {
            const {loading, currency} = this.state;
            console.log(currency); //only for debugging
            return (
                { loading? 'Loading...' : (
                <div>
                    <p>{currency.rates.RON}</p>
                </div>)
                }
            )
        }
```

Comment: I tried ```{this.state.currency.rates.RON}``` but it doesn't work at all , it gave me "TypeError: Cannot read property 'RON' of undefined"

Comment: @TingYuanLu weird! Could you console the values of currency and see if it has the service response or not. Check updated answer.